# Connecting React-native to ASP.NET Core Web API (NETWORK ERROR on react-native)

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this problem every time I try to connect my react-native app to my ASP.NET Core Web API. I tried to change my localhost to 127.0.0.1:PORT, also I tried conveyor to broadcast the API, and it didn't work. I've also tried to use postman and my Web API is working but every time I fetch it into my react-native it doesn't work.

```
const testApiConnection = async () => {
    try {
      // Replace the URL with the actual endpoint of your .NET Core API
      const apiUrl = 'https://192.168.1.80:45455/api/ApiCommuter/List'; // Replace 'YourController' with the actual controller name
  
      // Make a GET request to the API to fetch the list of commuters
      const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
  
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const commuters = response.data;
  
        // Log the list of commuters
        console.log('Connection test successful.');
        console.log('List of Commuters:', commuters);
      } else {
        // Log an error message for any issues
        console.log('Connection test failed: Error fetching the list of commuters');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Log any errors that occur during the request
      console.log('Connection test failed. Error: ', error);
    }
  };
```

C# Web API code:

```
[HttpGet("List")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Commuter>>> GetCommuter()
{
    return await _context.Commuter.ToListAsync();
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using SecurityMonitoringSystem.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SecurityMonitoringSystem
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(
                  Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddCors();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8081", "https://your-react-native-app.com")
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "generate",
                    pattern: "Drivers/Generate/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Drivers", action = "Generate" });
                            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you pls share the detailed error message?

Comment: Hello, error[network error]. This showed when I tried to connect to my Web Api. Thankfully I've resolved this using a conveyer (extension from VScode2022), and make use of the remoteUrl instead of the localhost and change the HTTPS into HTTP.